# c++ net library for https server: epoll cookie and session

Tags: c++, http, https, server

For some reason, I must use C++ to develop a https server.
I've found that some libraries could help to do this. Such as netlib, libmicrohttpd etc.

I have some basic questions:
1) When I developed a server with socket, I always use `epoll` and multithreading to process client requests. Now I'm trying to use some library to develop a https server with C++. If so, need I worry about socket I/O and multithreading? [Here](http://mikhailberis.github.io/cpp-netlib/hello_world_server.html) is an example of netlib, it is quite simple: no `epoll` no multithreading. Does it mean that the lower layer have handled all so that I can just focus on the process of requests?

2) Last time that I developed a server, I used PHP.
I know that there some special technique in web development. Such as Cookie and Session.
With PHP I can handle them easily. But I don't know if the libraries such as netlib offer some functions to do this too.

Comment: try any c++ http server using libuv https://github.com/0x00A/nodeuv-http

Comment: Socket I/O, multithreading and SSL are not related in a way that you must use them together. You can use some or all of these approaches, depending of your requirements. Do you have constraints regarding HTTPS server implementation? [Poco](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.html) has support for HTTPS. An HTTPS server example is given within the library code.

Comment: @karastojko  in fact what I'm developing is just s simple http server. Http or https is not very important for now but throughput capacity is. As a server, it must can handle many clients at one moment. When I worked with socket, I had learnt about c10k problem, which teaches us how to use `epoll` and multithreading to be able to process many clients. I don't know if I should worrying about the same issue when I use these net libraries, or these libraries have done their best so I can just focus on how to process requests.

Comment: POCO's HTTPServer inherits TCPServer which itself uses `poll`. I did some testing long time ago, and it was descent in terms of speed.